# Android Shared Preference - resets

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an Activity and Placeholder fragment.  I am trying to load a string value in a EditText box, and to save it once the Save button is pressed.  But after I switch back and forth between screens the EditText that should display that text does not display it. Instead it displays the text "android.widget.EditText{5282c35c VFED..CL.F......217,2-717,51 #7f08005d app:id/nameInfo".  I have no idea what this means.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Either how do I fix or what else can I use to save a string value.

```
public class MyInformation extends Activity {

public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
public static SharedPreferences settings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.personal_info_main);

    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance())
            .commit();
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_information, container, false);

        EditText name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nameInfo);

        name.setText(settings.getString("key_name", null));

        Button save = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Personal Information Saved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                EditText name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nameInfo);
                String nameAsString = name.toString();
                editor.putString("key_name", nameAsString);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
           String nameAsString = name.toString();
```

to

```
          String nameAsString = name.getText().toString();
```

Comment: That was my issue.  Thanks so much.  As you can tell, I'm just learning android programming!